# What happened to Shersoft and the ActiveListBar control?

Tags: .net, com

I have the task of maintaining an application that started life as a VB6 app and has been migrated up to .NET 3.5. This app contains several third-party COM controls, one of which is the Shersoft ActiveListBar control. I'm trying to get a couple new programmers set up to edit this project and we're running into a licensing issue and a pop-up telling us to contact Shersoft... a company which no longer exists. Does anyone know what happened to the ActiveListBar product, if it was purchased by and is being sold by another company?

(Yes, I realize the *proper* thing to do is pull the control from the codebase and replace with with .NET code, but there isn't time for that in the release schedule right now...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer:

Sheriden Software -- Shersoft -- and Protoview [merged in 2001 to create Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/about-us/press-room/press-releases/sheridan-protoview-merger.aspx). The SSActliveListBar control has since been updated/replaced with the [WinListBar control](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winlistbar.aspx).